autocorrelation using FFT
I am trying to translate this Python routine into C#:
import numpy as np

def autocorr(x):
    if not hasattr(x[0], "__len__"):#Check if one dimentional array
        length=len(x)
        N_padding=2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(2*len(x) - 1)).astype('int')#padding size is next power of 2 from 2*length of x -1
        x=np.pad(x, (N_padding,))#pad with zeroes on each sides
        fft=np.fft.fft(x)
        cfft=np.conjugate(fft)
        coefs=np.fft.ifft(fft*cfft)[:length]#Get the coefficients from the inverse fft of the product of fft and cfft
    else:#For two dimentional array
        x=np.transpose(x)
        length=len(x[0])
        coefs=[]
        N_padding=2 ** np.ceil(np.log2(2*len(x[0]) - 1)).astype('int')#padding size is next power of 2 from 2*length of x -1
        x_bis=[]
        for i in range(len(x)):#Do the padding along dimension 0
            x[i]=x[i]
            x_bis.append(np.pad(x[i], (N_padding,)))#pad with zeroes on each sides
        
        fft=np.fft.fft(x_bis)
        cfft=np.conjugate(fft)
        coefs=np.fft.ifft(fft*cfft)[:,:length].tolist()#Get the coefficients from the inverse fft of the product of fft and cfft
    return coefs
    
coefs=autocorr([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]])
if hasattr(coefs[0], "__len__"):
    for i in range(len(coefs)):
        coefs[i]/=np.arange(len(coefs[i]), 0, -1)#Divide each coefficients by the size of the vector minus it's index
        coefs[i]/=coefs[i][0]
print(coefs)

Output:
[array([1.        +0.j, 0.90909091+0.j, 0.78787879+0.j, 0.63636364+0.j,
       0.45454545+0.j]), array([1.        +0.j, 0.90909091+0.j, 0.78787879+0.j, 0.63636364+0.j,
       0.45454545+0.j]), array([1.        +0.j, 0.90909091+0.j, 0.78787879+0.j, 0.63636364+0.j,
       0.45454545+0.j])]

C# version
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Complex;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;

public class AutoCorrelation
{
    public static double[][] Autocorr(double[][] x)
    {
        int rows = x.Length;
        int cols = x[0].Length;

        // Convert input array to Matrix
        var matrix = Matrix<double>.Build.DenseOfRowArrays(x).Transpose();

        // Create a new matrix to hold the padded data
        int length = cols;
        int N_padding = (int)Math.Pow(2, Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(2 * length - 1, 2)));

        var paddedMatrix = Matrix<Complex>.Build.Dense(matrix.RowCount, N_padding, Complex.Zero);

        // Pad the matrix rows
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                paddedMatrix[i, j] = new Complex(matrix[i, j], 0);
            }
        }

        // Apply FFT to each row
        var fftMatrix = paddedMatrix.Clone();
        for (int i = 0; i < fftMatrix.RowCount; i++)
        {
            var rowArray = fftMatrix.Row(i).ToArray();
            Fourier.Forward(rowArray, FourierOptions.NoScaling);
            for (int j = 0; j < rowArray.Length; j++)
            {
                fftMatrix[i, j] = rowArray[j];
            }
        }

        // Apply conjugate FFT
        var cfftMatrix = fftMatrix.Conjugate();

        // Multiply fft and cfft matrices element-wise
        var productMatrix = fftMatrix.PointwiseMultiply(cfftMatrix);

        // Apply inverse FFT to each row
        for (int i = 0; i < productMatrix.RowCount; i++)
        {
            var rowArray = productMatrix.Row(i).ToArray();
            Fourier.Inverse(rowArray, FourierOptions.NoScaling);
            for (int j = 0; j < rowArray.Length; j++)
            {
                productMatrix[i, j] = rowArray[j];
            }
        }

        // Extract the coefficients
        var coefsMatrix = productMatrix.SubMatrix(0, productMatrix.RowCount, 0, length);

        // Convert to jagged array and normalize the coefficients
        var coefs = coefsMatrix.ToRowArrays().Select(row => row.Select(c => c.Real).ToArray()).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < coefs.Length; i++)
        {
            var firstElement = coefs[i][0];
            for (int j = 0; j < coefs[i].Length; j++)
            {
                coefs[i][j] /= (length - j);
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < coefs[i].Length; j++)
            {
                coefs[i][j] /= firstElement;
            }
        }

        return coefs;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        double[][] data = new double[][]
        {
            new double[] { 1, 1, 1 },
            new double[] { 2, 2, 2 },
            new double[] { 3, 3, 3 },
            new double[] { 4, 4, 4 },
            new double[] { 5, 5, 5 }
        };

        double[][] coefs = Autocorr(data);

        // Print the coefficients
        for (int i = 0; i < coefs.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < coefs[i].Length; j++)
            {
                System.Console.Write(coefs[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}


Output:
0.333333333333333 0.285714285714286 0.214285714285714
0.333333333333333 0.285714285714286 0.214285714285714
0.333333333333333 0.285714285714286 0.214285714285714
Press any key to continue . . .

The outputs are different - C# version is giving the incorrect output.
How can I fix the C# version?

Did you try FourierOptions.Matlab instead of FourierOptions.NoScaling?

Also, the python is applying the FFT column wise, hence the FFT has 5 records per list and not three...

I am pretty confident that the python code isn’t producing the correct results either. It certainly isn’t doing what the comments within it say it should do, which is roughly how I understand the autocorrelation should be calculated if you are using FFTs

There are quite a few problems with both the Python and the C# code from what I can see. As best as I can tell, the Python code is broken and won't produce correct results. If you faithfully follow the Python, you should get the same wrong answers. However, as you haven't you should not expect the same answers.
The biggest issue in the C# is that you have mixed the dimensions within the autocorrelation function. For the input you have defined, this:
int rows = x.Length;
int cols = x[0].Length;

is wrong. Because the routine operates in transposed order, it should be:
int rows = x[0].Length;
int cols = x.Length;

At that point, I think all the computations up to normalisation of the real part of the inverse FFT should be correct. But the normalisation of the real part of inverse FFT solution isn't correct because of the aforementioned reversal of rows and columns, but also because the Python you are translating is mathematically wrong, as far as I can tell. Amongst other problems, the Python zero pads the real data before (wrong) and after (correct), meaning that the fft-ifft cycle won't be correct. It then does some very odd normalization that I can't see being correct.
For reference, all that crufty Python could be replaced with:
def autocorr(x):

    x = np.atleast_2d(x)
    xlen = x.shape[-1]
    xfft = np.fft.fft(x, n=2*xlen-1) 
    xifft = np.fft.ifft(np.conjugate(xfft) * xfft)

    coeffs = xifft[:,:xlen].real / xlen
    coeffs /= coeffs[:,0].reshape(-1,1)
    return coeffs

Which works like this:
dset = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[34,56,23,45,21]])
print(autocorr(dset))

[[1.         0.72727273 0.47272727 0.25454545 0.09090909]
 [1.         0.7097571  0.51941814 0.37134623 0.09798271]]

This agrees with using the numpy built-in correlation function:
res = np.correlate(dset[0], dset[0], mode='full')/dset[0].size
res = res[res.size//2:]
res /= res[0]
print(res)

[1.         0.72727273 0.47272727 0.25454545 0.09090909]

You will need to rework the normalisation code accordingly. Then you will get a correct answer, but it won't match the output of the reference Python you are trying to follow, because that is wrong from what I can see.
Disclaimer: I've never written or even looked at any C# code until I wrote this answer and I'm making assumptions about the correct workings of the Mathnet routines, which I could not test online.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/651749/why-are-the-autocorrelation-computations-without-fft-and-with-fft-giving-differe

Straightforwardly, everything in that question you linked to is mathematically wrong as well. If, as you say, you have a set of vectors of length 3,  how can you possibly calculate the autocorrelation for lags 3 and 4? I think you would do us all a favour to get an introductory text on time series analysis and read it. You can’t write numerical code to perform an operation if you don’t understand its mathematical foundation, and you clearly don’t in this case

Here is a hint — what you are actually trying to do here (and there) is calculate the autocorrelation of [1,2,3,4,5]. The non mean centred solution is as in my answer, and the mean centred solution is [1, 0.4, -0.1, -0.4,-0.4]. And you can obtain it via a correctly implemented FFT method or by discrete calculation of the individual lags, if you use the correct formula, which you are presently not doing.
